# Determine if only one image attached to a post/page

Tags: php, images

I'm looking to determine how many images are attached to a post, specifically if there is only one. Basically if there are multiple images I want to display my slideshow script, if there is only one I want to display that image, and not load the slideshow.

I saw this on a similar post which determines if any images are attached:

```
$attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image') );

if ( $attachments ) {

// do conditional stuff here 

}
```

Can I use something similar to determine if there is only one image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code should get the attachments as array which you should be able to use [`count()`](http://www.php.net/count) on to determine the total number of images. Example:

```
if ( $attachments ) {
    if ( 1 == count( $attachments ) ) {
      // handle single image
    } else {
      // handle multiple images
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.